# In rails app who respond according to the http request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

Well, so far in each article I see people say server respond accordingly to the request type. If it is xml request then response is in xml and if it is ajax or html then response is in ajax or html. Browser send the request and server respond accordingly. My question is in rails app in which part this decision is taken? That is by server which part of the rails app we indicate?

Answer (score 0):

This decision is taken inside the controller of the rails MVC framework and can be modified by the user. The user may wish not to respond to a particular type of request.

Comment: I think I could not make myself clear. I know this is done in Controller. But my question is, browser send html/xml/json request and server respond. Who extract this info in rails server side that the request was made in html or xml and server has to respond accordingly?

Comment: The request header contains this information and the same is extracted in the function in the controller responding to the request.

Comment: what about xml or json request? Request header is same for xml and json. Then how it is extracted?

Answer (score 0):

The distinction is made by suffix in URI, eg. ..../users/123.json. And You do it by yourself in controller.